# Using the equals() method with String and Object in Java

Tags: java, string, equals

```
Object o1 = new Object();
Object o2 = new Object();
//o1=o2;
System.out.println(o1.equals(o2));
```

It returns `false`. It can return `true`, if the comment is removed.

---

Why isn't the same thing applicable to the `String` class?

```
String s1=new String();
String s2=new String();
System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
```

It returns `true`. Why? (because `String` uses interns or something else involved?)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because **[equals() for String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)** compares the content, not the object itself.

> public boolean equals(Object anObject)
>
> Compares this string to the specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a `String` object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

```
    /* String.equals() */
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String)anObject;
        int n = count;
        if (n == anotherString.count) {
            char v1[] = value;
            char v2[] = anotherString.value;
            int i = offset;
            int j = anotherString.offset;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

(Link to the source of [String.equals()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.equals%28java.lang.Object%29))

Versus the **[equals for Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)**:

> The equals method for class `Object` implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values `x` and `y`, this method returns true if and only if `x` and `y` refer to the same object (`x == y` has the value `true`).

```
/* Object.equals() */
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

(Link to the source of [Object.equals()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Object.java#Object.equals%28java.lang.Object%29))

Also, don't forget the contract of the `equals()` function:

> The equals method implements an equivalence relation on non-null object references:
>
> - It is **reflexive**: for any non-null reference value `x`, `x.equals(x)` should return true.
> - It is **symmetric**: for any non-null reference values `x` and `y`, `x.equals(y)` should return true if and only if `y.equals(x)` returns true.
> - It is **transitive**: for any non-null reference values `x`, `y`, and `z`, if `x.equals(y)` returns `true` and `y.equals(z)` returns `true`, then `x.equals(z)` should return `true`.
> - It is **consistent**: for any non-null reference values `x` and `y`, multiple invocations of `x.equals(y)` consistently return `true` or consistently return `false`, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the objects is modified.
> - For any non-null reference value `x`, `x.equals(null)` should return `false`.

Also recommended reading:

- **[Object.hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)**
- **[Effective Java (Bloch)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)**

Comment: In addition to the `Object` class, the same thing happens with a class that we create. Why? Does it use the `Object` class method?

Comment: @Tiny If you don't override `equals` in your class, it will inherit Object's `equals` method.

Comment: @Tiny Because every class descends from Object. You should override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods for your own classes, else they will use those of the `Object` class.

Comment: `s1==s2` and `s1.equals(s2)` both are different I can understand. From the specification, it appears that both `o1==o2` and `o1.equals(o2)` are same. Do they?

Comment: @Tiny Why not just read the code for [Object](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Object.java#Object.equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and for [String](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.equals%28java.lang.Object%29)?

Comment: `o1.equals(o2)` is only the same as `o1 == o2` if the class of `o1` didn't override the `equals` implementation from `Object`.

Answer (score 9):

`equals` for `Object` compares memory references.
That is why it is false since they are different `Object`s
`equals` for `String` is overridden to compare based on characters.
You have 2 empty `String` objects that is why `equals` returns `true`.

Comment: Are `o1==o2` and `o1.equals(o2)` same (both are objects as specified in the question)? They appear to be the same from the specification.

Comment: Yes. `equals` of `Object` does: `return this == o2`

Answer (score 5):

`==` compares addresses of the objects / strings / anything

`.equals()` designed to use internal state of the objects for comparison.

So:

`new Object() == new Object() => false` - two separate object at different addresses in memory.

`new String("a") == new String("a") => false` - the same situation - two separate addresses for the string objects.

`new String("a").equals(new String("a")) => true` - addresses differ, but Java will took one object state ('a') and compared with other object state ('a') will found them equal and will report true.

Using the equals() method you can code the comparison any way is proper for your program.

`intern()` is a bit different story. It is intended to return same object (address) for the same char sequence. It is useful to reduce amount of memory required when you have same strings constructed several times.

`new String("aaa").intern()` will seek in the machine memory if ever someone created "aaa" string before and will return the first instance of the String ... If non has been found - the current one will be enlisted as the first and all further "aaa".intern() and new `String("aaa").intern()` and `("a"+"aa").intern()` will return that "first" instance.

Beware: `"aaa".intern()` is not very fast operation and if you will intern all strings - you will save some memory, but will loose quite a lot of CPU work.

Comment: Are `o1==o2` and `o1.equals(o2)` same (both are objects as specified in the question)? Do you know?

Answer (score 2):

The `equals` implemented in the `Object` class only compare references. Here is the source code:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
return (this == obj);
}
```

Comment: Are `o1==o2` and `o1.equals(o2)` same (both are objects as specified in the question)? They appear to be the same from the specification.

Comment: @Tiny Only in your first case, when you create two instances of Object class. In your seconde case you create instances of String class, which overrides the equals method and then compare both objects to see if they have the same text inside.

Answer (score 2):

equals method needs to be overridden inside the class if you want to make it behave in some other way. By default, it checks if two references refer to the same object.

Comment: Are `o1==o2` and `o1.equals(o2)` same (both are objects as specified in the question)? They appear to be the same from the specification.

Answer (score 2):

The `equals()` Method of the `Object` class doesn't know how to compare Strings, it only knows how to compare objects. For comparing strings, a string class will override the `equals()` Method and compare strings in it.

`Object.equals()` will compare only references, where `String.equals()` will compare values.

Answer (score 0):

Interesantly unlike the `Sting` the `StringBuffer` does not override the `equals()` method. Its functionality is the same as for the `Object` class.